# Sharepoint 2010 Calculated Column: How to get value before item gets modified?

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, modified, comparison

I have a list that has a Status-field. If the status changes, a modified date in another column should indicate, when the status has been changed.

My idea was to create a duplicate of this Status-Column and create in a column, where the date is supposed to be, a function something like this:

```
=IF(NOT([Status]=[StatusDuplicate]),[Modified],[Stay like that(not specified yet)])
```

However, this (of course) doesn't work properly. The Modified-Date-field gets updated even if I just "edit" the item with no changes.

Does someone know a solution/workaround to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the timestamp when the status column changed. See the link below for further details.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b0aae71a-1f53-4ded-8cef-342c4d3f822e/capturing-timestamp-when-status-changes-in-a-sharepoint-2010-list?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

/* Updated in 2/27/2018 */

If you want to show the timestamp when the status is not the starting status, you can use:

```
=IF(NOT(Status="Start"),TEXT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mm"),IF(ISBLANK(Status),"","NULL"))
```

This should work, let me know if you have any question.s

Comment: Hello YogaPanda. Thanks a lot for the helpful answer.
I can't not use the code-solution, as I don't have the permissions (and not the knowledge).

The other solution works. The only problem is that when I edit the item without changing the status, the calculated column thinks that the status has been changed regardless and writes a new date

Comment: What's your starting status, and what are the status choices you have? I can write a custom calculated formula for you. See the updated answer :)

Comment: Hi @sholli I have tested the link provided above and it works like a charm. Your first formula is showing the modified timestamp when the item is changed (because you use the modified column instead of NOW function.)

Comment: Thanks @YogaPanda, you're very kind to help me. Yes the formula works.  However, the date changes even if the status doesn't get modified. For example:
I change the status of an item to "Resolved". The formula creates  a timestamp. That's good. The next day I edit the item (write in comments field) but let status be on "Resolved". I save and it creates a new timestamp. That's not good because I need to know the status 
change date.

But I use another way now. I just let the user write the date manually. It's not optimal but it works. I thank you a lot for your helpful tips :-)